# WIthMockUser doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-test-mvc

I can't use @WithMockUser, no matter what I do it doesn't provide authorized user in spring test. Maybe it's because its resource server but..

Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter 
...
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .anonymous().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER");
}
...
}
```

And test class

```
@BeforeClass
public void setup(){
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(wac)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
}


@Test
@WithMockUser()
public void shouldAddValueToStore() throws Exception {
ResultActions response = mockMvc.perform(post("/bucket/key")
            .content("value"));
...
}
```

I keep getting 401 `Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point`. I've tried with setting usernames, roles in annotation parameters, passing `with(user..)` to mockMvc, nothing helps. It's spring security 4.0.4.RELEASE.

Comment: @WithMockUser(username = "ram", authorities={"ROLE_XX","ROLE_AA"}) or username could be omitted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, it works after setting 'stateless' parameter to 'false' as described here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/385

and using `with(user..`

```
ResultActions response = mockMvc.perform(post("/bucket/key")
            .with(user("john@example.com"))
            .content("value"));
```

WithMockUser is still not working, but this method is good enough for now.

Comment: What's about WithMockUser, this seems to be quite convenient annotation.